# Structure of topological spaces in terms of sequences

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I been reading for several hours and not yet found a question put in this way.
Given any topological space:

1. Does every sequance in $X$ determine a countable subset of $X$?
2. Do the sets that belong the a topology on $X$ (the open sets) separete these sequences (given 1. is true) and therefore supply a structure for "the set $X$" turning it into a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a sequence of comments on the other answer, I believe Question 2 is asking:

**Is a topology uniquely determined by its convergent sequences?**

The answer to this question is **no**.  For a counterexample, let $\omega_1$ be the [first uncountable ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal), and consider $\omega_1 + 1 = \omega_1 \cup \{\omega_1\}$ under the [order topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology).  Every neighborhood of $\omega_1$ then contains infinitely many elements, thus $\omega_1$ is not an isolated point, but no sequence converges to $\omega_1$ (any countable increasing sequence of ordinals necessarily has a countable limit ordinal).

Sometimes we generalize the concept of sequences to [nets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29), which *do* capture all information about the topology of a space.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**
No, the sequence $\{x_n=1\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite sequence finite subset of $X$. Unless you mean something else by "determine a countable infinite subset".

**Question 2**
I'm not entirely sure what you are asking here. You're question seems somewhat circular or trivial since the open sets of $X$ will by definition "supply a structure for "the set $X$" and turn it into a space" - the open sets form the topology of $X$. Moreover, it seems that your second question does not rely on whether or not Question 1 was true or false.

Comment: I confused myself..lets just say a countable subset.

Comment: @Johan, what is the definition of `countable` to you? Countable means bijection with $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Johan Sequences are inherently countable (unless you are talking of some sort of transfinite sequence over the ordinals, however, I don't believe that is what you mean.

Comment: What Im asking in 2 is if these sequances determine subsets then the whole purpose of the topology is to seperate them by open sets

Comment: @Johan In what sense do you mean that a sequence "determines" a subset? A sequence in $X$ is a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$, and I interpreted the "determined" subset to be the image of $f$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @ChristianBueno Yes

Comment: @Johan Well a sequence (as I defined earlier) will always have a countable image and the answer to question 1 will always be trivially yes.

Also, when you ask if the open sets turn $X$ into a a space, what do you mean? The open sets certainly make $X$ into a topological space (by definition), so what kind of space are you asking about?

Comment: @ChristianBueno This image will not always belong to the topology unless its the indiscrete topology, I guess. Im looking to understand any topological space,but let me try to restate my idea. A topology is a structure that distinguishes sequences or aleast tires to. A set of two points beloning to the topology where the singeltons of both points do not belong to the topology would not be indistinguishable, since there wont be a sequance with only finite number of one of the point and infinite number of the other .

Comment: @Johan You never asked about whether the sequence itself forms an open set, you only asked if it is a subset, which was trivially true. And you actually could have a sequence as you described in your comment, however due to the topology, it would not converge.

Comment: @ChristianBueno Right, it could be a open, closed, clopen, "a neigbourhood of a point" or just nither of those

Comment: @Johan Are you only concerned with convergent sequences in $X$?

Comment: @ChristianBueno no, any sequance really. Convergent sequances are just a certin kind of sequances defined on a set that has all but finitly many belonging to open sets right? My main concern is how sequences relate to subsets. My second question however might have seem trivial, it was just point of view I never seen expressed explicitly

Comment: @Johan What do you mean how sequences relate to subsets? The image of a sequence of points in $X$ is a subset of $X$. What other relationship are you looking for? To me it seems that the first question is trivial, and the second is not worded properly.

Comment: @ChristianBueno Enlgish is not my mother tongue, I might not use the words properly. Anyway the whole point of the question was really to find out if you could consider topology as study of infinite sequences and their abiltity to converge given a topology instead of subsets which seems more natural to me after reading for almost two months. Since a sequance determine a unique subset but a subset does not determine a unique sequence.But maybe Im missing something.

Comment: @Johan Would this be related to what you are looking for?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space

Comment: @ChristianBueno hmm every topology I worked with so far seems to be of this kind, maybe thats why i think its general anyway there is an exampel where this not hold. Ill read more about that, thanks for your patience!